# Is it possible to use services in different regions in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, region

Say there are two AWS services A and B which forms part of infrastructure of an application

1. Is it possible to use say service A in region X and service B in region Y in AWS.
2. Is it recommended.
3. What advantages do we get when we design our application like this , (if any)
4. Going through [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html) and [this](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-choose-the-best-aws-region-for-your-workload/), i have learnt that we should use regions to avoid latency issues and use Availability Zones to replicate the infrastructure thereby achieving robustness. Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Of course,it is possible to provision your services in different
   regions.
2. It depends, in general if you have application which consists
       of service A and service B - I don't think it would be a good
       decision, because if (in theory)  you loose service A in region X  -
       service B in region Y makes no sense as it depends on A and cannot
       fully operate.

   More preferable approach is to have application configured fully in
   2 regions (service A and B in region X load balanced not even weight
   in region Y which also has A and B services). In this scenario:

   - you **will not loose** your application operation **entirely**
   - you will be able to provide best response time for appropriate customer (for example -  APAC clients can be served in region X,
     EMEA ones - in region Y)
3. This is correct. If you have services A in region X and service B in region Y - you can definitely run into latency issues. The difference will be noticeable. Last statement is based on our experiments in AWS.